# When transferring a website from a server to another server/heroku, does your google ranking and indexes become affected?

Tags: search, heroku, dns

I have a django application that I'm hosting on a digital ocean server. I have quite a bit of content that I've built up on there which google has indexed. Now if I transfer that django app to heroku and then point the domains DNS to heroku will that preserve all the indexing done by search engines? I believe the answer is yes but I just want to be sure im not missing anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct; Google isn't aware of what your technology stack looks like, only of the HTML output for each page.

Make sure that the transfer doesn't result in a slower page load time or broken links, though.